# Visual studio code error :-Failed to start flow Error: Wrong version of Flow. The config specifies version ^0.92.0 but this is version 0.95.1

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

Hello I am a beginner in React-native and below is my flowconfig file's version and I get an error with this version

```
[version]
^0.92.0
```

Is there a way to fix this error, I was trying to run debug mode in visual code for running react-native projects and to print console.log.
So far I am unsuccessful.

PS:- beginner in react-native

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change `[version]` in the `.flowconfig` to match the installed version, `^0.95.1`

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: I did that but the error reappears and my Debugging in visual code is not working. break points etc won't get hit.

Comment: Did you try restarting vscode? Debugger problems might be a different issue

Comment: Good old "have tried turning it off and on again?" :)

Comment: This is ridiculous. What if you want to update flow, not just degrade the existing codebase?

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Check that the following tags match

`package.json`

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "flow-bin": "0.130.0"
}
```

`.flowconfig`

```toml
[version]
^0.130.0
```

#### 2. Clean & Reinstall

If they match, this error can occur when your `node_modules` are out of sync with the version of [`flow-bin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-bin) in your `package.json`. This can occur if you've changed branches recently or have have an older version in your node modules.

Try removing and reinstalling like this:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the flow version make it a ranged version. For example something like `>=0.50.0` or simply remove the version altogether. You can read about that more in the [flowconfig docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/version/)

I find that changing the flow version every time you face this problem to be a bad approach especially if you work with a team and each team member has a different version installed and they would commit their version into the `.flowconfig` file

Comment: Great answer, both mentioned approaches work fine. Worth mentioning that the `^` in front of the version also specifies a range, but below version 0 this will only have an effect on the third digit. 75% of `flow-bin` releases have been major releases so far, which is pretty unusual.